# Is there a way to alias a location in Cygwin for a shebang?

Tags: cygwin, shebang

I have some scripts that I often use in both windows(cygwin) and linux, I'd like to make the scripts executable in both environments.  Is there a way to alias the location of my python installation, for example so that

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

will still find my python installation, even though, as far as cygwin is concerned, it is located at `/cygdrive/c/Python26/python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Python via Cygwin's `setup.exe`, and it will be in `/usr/bin`.

Or create symbolic links on both systems, for example in `/usr/local/bin/python`, and use that in the shebang.

Or write an installation script that adjusts the `#!` line in your Python scripts as it installs them.

Note that if your `/cygdrive/c/Python26/python` (`C:\Python26\python`) is a native Windows Python installation, scripts using it won't be able to use Cygwin-style paths.

Answer (score 0):

Put /cygdrive/c/Python26/python in your PATH variable, and replace the shebang line with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

assuming that cygwin can run that version of python.

Comment: That's a common solution, but it has some drawbacks; see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).